# Import Data into Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server

I would like to import all of my Scrum based data into an existing Visual Studio Online account. Whether it is from Microsoft Excel, API, etc. I would like to migrate old data into VSO.

How can I do this?

Thank you.

**Edit:** I am referring to backlog items, sprints, bugs, etc. that we have in another Scrum-based planning tool.

Comment: you can't create a team project, add your files to a solution in VS, and check them in?

Comment: I am not talking about code; I am referring to stuff like backlogs; bugs; sprints; work items, etc.,

Comment: IDK about VSO specifically, but you can check any kind of file into TFS. just add it to a solution, and check it in.

Comment: Have you tried with "StoCazzoOnline" ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Team** tab in Excel to connect to the VSTS instance.

Connect to your team project hosted in VSTS.

Make sure your cursor is in a cell that contains data, otherwise the Publish button might appear disabled.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=vsts

Answer (score -1):

If you are still looking you could try MS Project Professional. Connect to TFS under the "Team" tab and import/publish data. there are a couple things that won't be loaded (like Active) but most will go.